# Какой метод жизненного цикла фрагмента вызывается при возвращении во фрагмент

Tags: java, android

Имею стек в который сохраняю фрагменты, существует проблема для решения которой мне нужно менять значение переменной при возвращении во фрагмент. Какой метод жизненного цикла фрагмента для этого подойдет или может есть какой-то другой вариант? Под возвращением имею ввиду то, что из стека достается фрагмент.

```
@Override
public void setMenuVisibility(boolean isvisible) {
    super.setMenuVisibility(isvisible);
    if (isvisible){
        Log.d("Viewpager", "fragment is visible ");
    }else {
        Log.d("Viewpager", "fragment is not visible ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Могут разные методы вызываться в зависимости от того как именно вы фрагменты отображаете. Попробуйте вот такой варинат, например: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48893052/3212712

Comment: @ЮрийСПб так как setUserVisibleHint устарел, то пробовал через setMenuVisibility, но по какой-то причине ничего не работает, прикрепил пример того, что я пробовал

Comment: OnCreate всегда вызывается

Comment: @ArtyMorris, это не так. Если фрагменты добавлять, а не заменять, а потом вернуться на ранее добавленный, то он не будет создан заново, т.к. даже не будет уничтожен и будет виден юзеру, если фрагмент поверх него имеет прозрачный фон.

Comment: @Shadowlight, попробуйте onResume тогда

Comment: @ЮрийСПб сейчас попробую, кстати, я проверил и в моем случаие все переменные (массивы и тд) сохраняются при добавлении в стек и при возвращении остаются теми же

Comment: @ЮрийСПб onResume, не подходит, так как он вызывается еще и при первом отображении фрагмента

Comment: Если это не подходит, то надо совсем иначе всё делать. Колбэка именно возврата несуществует. Возможно для вашего случая (вы не сформулировали полностью задачу, засим сложно точно сказать) подойдёт что то типа FragmentResult. Точно не помню как оно называется

Answer (score 0):

В моей ситуации мне подошел `onDestroyView()`, который вызывается при смене фрагмента. При смене фрагмента я меняю нужные мне значения в методе `onDestroyView()` и сохраняю его в стек.